# invalid use of member 'MainWindow::account' in static member function

Tags: c++, qt

Qt. Из одного файла передаю объект класса в другой файл. Вод код mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <string>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mainmenu.h" // для создания объекта окна mainmenu чтобы переходить в это окно 

using namespace std;
class RegData;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    RegData *account; // для передачи в другое окно
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_button_reg_clicked();

    void on_button_log_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Mainmenu *second;
};
class RegData
{
private:
    QString login;
    QString email;
    QString password;
public:
    RegData(QString log = "", QString mail = "", QString pass = "") : login(log), email(mail), password(pass)
    {
    }
    RegData(const RegData& src) :
        login(src.login), email(src.email), password(src.password)
    {
    }
    void cpy(const RegData& from)
    {
        login = from.login;
        email = from.email;
        password = from.password;
    }

    void output()
    {
        qDebug() << login<<email<<password;
    }
    QString getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }
    QString getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    QString getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    void setLogin(const QString log)
    {
        login = log;
    }
    void setEmail(const QString mail)
    {
        email = mail;
    }
    void setPassword(const QString pass)
    {
        password = pass;
    }
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Передавать файл мне нужно в mainmenu.cpp, вот он:

```
#include "mainmenu.h"
#include "ui_mainmenu.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

Mainmenu::Mainmenu(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Mainmenu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Mainmenu::~Mainmenu()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Mainmenu::on_plus_clicked()
{
    QString name = MainWindow::account->getLogin(); // здесь ошибка
    ui->label->setText(name);
}
```

В mainwindow.cpp я присваиваю значения для передаваемого объекта путем копирования через функцию (в классе) "cpy". Где ошибка я написал выше в комментарии к коду, а вот сама ошибка:

> C:\Users\david\Documents\Carsharring_files\mainmenu.cpp:19: ошибка: invalid use of non-static data member 'MainWindow::account'
> QString name = MainWindow::account->getLogin();
> ^

Если написать

```
static RegData *account;
```

выводит

> mainwindow.cpp167: ошибка: undefined reference to `MainWindow::account'

в указанной строке присваивание (копирование функция) account->cpy(*it);

Надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка буквально означает то, что вы делаете неправильно. Ваш класс `MainWindow` содержит поле `public: RegData *account`, но оно не является статическим членом класса. Не статические члены существуют только внутри объекта класса и к ним невозможно получить доступ не обращаясь к объекту. Обращение через `MainWindow::account` подразумевает, что это поле должно быть статическим, то есть объявление должно выглядеть так:

```
static RegData *account;
```

Но вообще старайтесь избегать использования public полей, это нарушает принцип инкапсуляции и делает код запутаннее. Поэтому, если возможно, лучше передавать объект, к полю которого будет идти обращение.

Также, поскольку Вы используете Qt, то для передачи данных между объектами можете использовать механизм слотов и сигналов.

Также, поскольку идёт работа с указателем, то необходимо выделить память, а в конце работы её очистить. То есть перед использованием поля `account` необходимо выделить место под объект класса RegData: `MainWindow::account = new RegData();`. А в конце программы сделать `delete MainWindow::account;`. Также существуют [умные указатели](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), которые избавляют от вопроса уборки памяти.

Comment: Я так пробовал уже, пишет mainwindow.cpp:95: ошибка: undefined reference to `MainWindow::account' это строка, где идет копирование. account->cpy(*it);

Comment: @Nedaxses Я только сейчас заметил, где вы выделяете память под этот объект? Это же указатель, чтобы он указывал куда-то, ему нужно присвоить адрес реального объекта в памяти для начала. То есть в каком-то месте `MainWindow::account = new RegData`.

Comment: Ознакомитесь с такими темами, как указатели(работа с памятью), ссылки для подобных действий. А также, поскольку это Qt изучите механизм сигналов и слотов, Вам это упростит работу с подобными вещами.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, посмотрю сигналы и слоты. Но уж очень интересно разобраться таким запутанным методом) Я пробовал объявить таким образом RegData *account = new RegData; но там тоже ошибки. mainwindow.h:23: ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type 'class RegData'

Comment: Тут Вы столкнулись с тем, что у вас класс сначала объявляется, а затем уже определяется. Замените объявление определением, а лучше перенесите в отдельный файл и подключайте уже этот файл. Не забывайте ставить рейтинг, если информация была для вас полезна, в этом смысл SO)

Comment: Спасибо! Поставил объявление сначала и заработало)